# Bash script: how to skip a header line when sorting a text or csv file, while retaining it in the output

Tags: bash, stdin, io-redirection, subshell

(Adapted from this: [Join Manual, Header lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Header-lines)).

I am sorting a file called file1 with this content:

```
Name   Age
Charlie 34
Alice   25
```

If I just write:

`sort -k2b,2 file1`

I get:

```
Alice   25
Charlie 34
Name   Age
```

I can exclude the header from the sort like so:

`head -1 file1 ;(sed -n '2,$p' file1|sort -k2b,2)`

But the example in the gnu manual is this:

`( sed -u 1q ; sort -k2b,2 ) < file1`

Why does that work?

I would think that I would get this instead from the command-line:

```
Name   Age
Alice   25
Charlie 34
Name   Age
```

The sed consumes the first line of stdin, then the sort consumes the rest?

Comment: *`The sed consumes the first line of stdin, then the sort consumes the rest?`* - yes, `sed` strips the 1st line off stdin and dumps to stdout while the `sort` is fed the rest of stdin and then dumps to stdout

Comment: by default `sed` is going to buffer the input so if the volume of input can fit into the initial buffer then `1q` will print the first line and discard the contents of the buffer, which means nothing is passed to `sort`; the `-u` tells `sed` to *not* buffer anything, to read/process one line at a time, so when `sed` hits `q` the rest of stdin is still available to be passed to `sort`

Comment: The important concept is that both `sed` and `sort` are reading from the same stream, not independent openings of the file. So `sort` starts reading from where `sed` ended.

Comment: `( head -n 1 ; sort -k2b,2 ) < file` should work too

Comment: So should `{ head -n 1 ; sort -k2b,2 ; } < file` with one fewer subprocesses .

Comment: @KamilCuk `read` (by itself) discards the 1st line; perhaps something like `read -r hdr; echo "$hdr";`

Answer (score 0):

You could have sed print the header, then sort the rest.

```bash
sed -n '1p' file1; sort <(sed '1d' file1)
```

```
Name   Age
Alice   25
Charlie 34
```